# What do you call the exploitation of ambiguous statements to form a logical argument?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, rhetoric

If I were construct an argument containing the postulation

> Men commit more crimes than women.

I would be guilty of a logical fallacy because this statement implies

1. All men commit crimes.
2. The man who commits the fewest crimes still commits more than the woman who commits the most crimes.

There is a name of this type of logical fallacy.  I think it is a kind of *hasty generalization*, but I'm not sure which.  Can someone please help me find the right term?

EDIT:

So to try to clarify what I'm asking (since I don't have the right lingo apparently), I think I have worked out that there are really two parts to this question.

We can agree that the predicate "Men commit more crimes than women" is *ambiguous*.

Ambiguity is not a friend of logic; so firstly what might you call a statement that requires disambiguation before it can be considered acceptable in an argument?

Secondly, is there a term that describes the exploitation of ambiguous statements to further an argument? (Is this a logical fallacy? If so, what kind? If not, what else might we call it?)

Comment: Simply *using* this statement isn’t necessarily a logical fallacy.  A generalisation like “men commit more crimes than women” is ambiguous, and can be taken as meaning several different things, some quite reasonable; the fallacy is in conflating different meanings of it.  (For instance, if Prof. X publishes research showing “men on average commit more crimes than women”, journalist Y headlines this as “men commit more crimes than women”, and Prof. Z then cites X’s research to justify that “every man commits more crimes than every woman” — *this* is a logical fallacy.)

Comment: The statement implies neither of the conclusions you draw.

Comment: This seems more on-topic for the [philosophy.SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2578/philosophy) site. They're almost a beta site, so commit to put them over the edge!

Comment: @Kit: yes, but my point is that you *can* reasonably use it in a logical argument, so long as you’re clear and consistent about what exactly you mean by it.  I agree with your general point, though — there is a common logical fallacy involving generalisations like this, and it probably has a conventional name (and if it doesn’t, it ought to).

Comment: It's not a *logical* fallacy but a *linguistic* (or more precisely a *pragmatic*) faulty argument: concluding from a somewhat vague statement a conclusion which follows only from an unlikely reading of the original statement. Not so much a generalisation, as an unwarranted conclusion.

Comment: @Colin Fine, not even that (in the way I read it); OP claims that there is a fallacy in the postulation (he presents implications, which are indeed incorrect i.e. not implications at all, as proof that there is an error in reasoning).

Comment: I would simply retort: You mean, _More crimes are committed by men than by women_

Comment: The example given might not be a fallacy but consider, "men are smarter than women" (based on Nobel prizes) or "black men are healthier than white men" (based on 100m gold medals)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While reading through some of the other questions on this site, I found [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27404/what-is-a-word-for-a-question-that-has-no-answer-because-it-is-seemingly-invalid/27409#comment-47454), which suggests the word [sophistry](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sophistry):

> **Sophistry:** a subtle, tricky, superficially plausible, but generally fallacious method of reasoning.

This term seems very suitable for my purposes.  I suggested that the respondent submit it as an answer to this question, but no one has done so.  Therefore, I'm submitting it, and accepting it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the two conclusions that you draw do not come from

> Men commit more crimes than women

but from

> Every man commits more crimes than any woman.

Without qualifiers (all, some, none) the proposition can mean that *men on average commit more crimes than women*.

Secondly, regardless of what is actually the initial phrase, to talk about [fallacies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacy) you *should have some reasoning* which you do not present, you only present a simple proposition.

EDIT (after question clarified)

In rhetorics the vice of ambiguity is called simply that - [ambiguity](http://www.sitelevel.com/click?url=http://rhetoric.byu.edu/figures/A/ambiguous.htm&sid=8JAkTGP3eYEU6VhT) (related terms: [amphibologia](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/figures/A/amphibologia.htm) and also [ambigua](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_rhetorical_terms)).

In logic the [incomplete comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_comparison) might be the correct term.

Once you have established a logical fallacy in the premise that should (normally) be enough to classify the conclusion as faulty, too.

Comment: Another viable interpretation of this sentence would be "men (as a group) commit more crimes than women (as a group)." This is semantically equivalent to mplungjan's "More crimes are committed by men than by women."

Comment: @sanderle, true - and in that case it is not ambiguous, but I acceept OPs clarifiction that in his context it is ambigous (by ommital of quantificators).

Comment: @Unreason, oh, I agree that it's ambiguous, and I think (after considering the question more) that the terms you've offered are probably right. (However, I prefer the IEP's explanation of [Amphiboly](http://www.iep.utm.edu/fallacy/#Amphiboly). "Elephants, please stay in your car.")

Answer (score 2):

From [Internet Encyclopedia of Phylosophy](http://www.iep.utm.edu/fallacy/)

```
Faulty Generalization
```

A fallacy produced by some error in the process of generalizing. See Hasty Generalization or Unrepresentative Generalization for examples.

Comment: +1 for link, but I still think that no fallacy is presented (though your answer might be exactly what OP wants)

Answer (score 0):

More a comment than an answer, but too long to fit in as a comment:

Perhaps this is just a flaw in the wording of the question, but there is no logical fallacy in the original statement. It is a statement of fact that can be shown to be true or false statistically. (And any statistics I've seen show it to be true.) If in a particular place in a particular period of time, there are 100,000 crimes committed by men and 50,000 crimes committed by women, then the statement is true.

There is a certain ambiguity in that it is not clear whether you mean "on average" or "total". For example, suppose you said -- and I'm just making this up as an example, these aren't real statistics -- "men with beards commit more crimes than men without". Suppose in the area in question there are 1,000 men with beards and 9,000 men without, and there are 100 crimes committed by men with beards and 450 crimes committed by men without. Then as a total, men without beards commit more crimes: 450 versus 100. But on average, men with beards commit more crimes: 10% versus 5%.

The conclusions you state do not follow logically from the original statement. I think this is a pretty classic case of a "non sequiter". Just because the AVERAGE member of group A does more of something than the AVERAGE member of group B, doesn't mean that EVERY member of group A does more than ANY member of group B. ETc.